# passing multiple parameter in Post method

Tags: ios, http-post, nsurlconnection

I am new to IOS I need to pass multiple parameter in Post method.I am successfully passed one parameter in post method but multiple parameter.
Code which I have done:

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@",str];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){

        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

Comment: With which part are you struggling? Add the parameter to your method or to the post body ?

Comment: NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&type=%@&name=%@",str,str_name,str_type];

Comment: i want to pass three parameter in which that 3 parameter can fetch from different url and i converted into string format that string only i want to pass as parameter that can possible with your code @BhavinRamani

Comment: i want to pass three parameter string in method and [self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str]; here @rckoenes

Answer (score 0):

You can send POST method Params as Dictionary.

Create as following :

**For JSON :**

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[params setValue:@"18" forKey:@"branch_id"];

[params setValue:@"OMR" forKey:@"branch_name"];

[params setValue:@"Chennai" forKey:@"branch_city"];
```

You can add your parameters as given above.

After that, convert this dictionary to Data and Pass it to htmlBody method as following :

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

After this, convert

```
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

**For Form-Data :**

```
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&branch_name=%@",branch_id,branch_name];
```

Then convert it to data as you did. After that, set it to htmlBody as Data.

Hope it helps..

Comment: This is great if you want to post JSON, but the code posted in the question is a form post. So posting JSON is not going to work.

Comment: Updated my answer. @rckoenes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send more parameter pass all the information.

```
NSString *parameter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@”firstname=%@&lastname=%@”,firstName, lastName]; //Parameter values from user.

        NSData *parameterData = [parameter dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [theRequest addValue: @”application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8″ forHTTPHeaderField:@”Content-Type”];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@”POST”];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:parameterData];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

        if( connection )
        {
        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }
        }
```